# Can not draw on Canvas on IOS

Tags: canvas, dart

I am trying to draw something with Dart on Canvas: Sort of:

```dart
_canvas = $["canvas"];
_context2d = _canvas.context2D;

_canvas.width = WIDTH;
_canvas.height = HEIGHT;


_context2d .lineTo(width, 0);
_context2d .lineTo(width, height);
_context2d .lineTo(0, height);
_context2d .lineTo(0, 0);
_context2d .stroke();
```

But nothing is displayed on IOS(Iphone and Ipad).

Try to run http://dev.photo-state.com/dart/ on iphone and ipad :( no luck.

Dart issue: Issue 15780:

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

there's an issue with IOS that canvas inside a custom element won't work

in my case I had to create a canvas outside of polymer and pass its id to my polymer which finds it and then draws on it - works like a charm

this didn't work for me `<custom-elem><canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas></custom-elem>`

this worked for me `<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas><custom-elem canvadId="myCanvas"></custom-elem>`